Derivation of equation from Euler's equation for a fluid
I'm having trouble with the formula for particle velocity of a standing wave in a tube, starting from conservation of mass and Euler's equation for a fluid. I've checked a few books and unfortunately none of them explain this particular step and I can't quite guess at what has been done to obtain the resultant formulas. I'm probably overlooking something basic. Here's an example from Theoretical Acoustics by Morse & Ingaard:
Suppose there are two simple-harmonic waves propagating in a 1D tube, one in the positive $x$ direction and one in the negative $x$ direction. The total sound field is given by their sum: $$p(x,t)=p_+ + p_- =A_+e^{i(kx-\omega t)}+A_-e^{-i(kx-\omega t)}$$
where $k=2\pi/\lambda$ is the wavenumber, and the speed of sound is given by $c=\omega/k$ where $\omega$ is the angular velocity.
From Euler's equation for a fluid with zero viscosity$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=-\rho \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$$ and conservation of mass $$\kappa\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$
where $\kappa$ is the compressibility and $\rho$ is density we can obtain that the fluid velocity at $x$, $t$ is $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{i\omega p}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$$
I would appreciate any clarification as to how the above result was obtained as it doesn't seem like it was arrived at via a straightforward process of integration.

Should your waves have $kx - \omega t$ and $kx + \omega t$?

As far as I can tell I think they should be $kx-\omega t$ and $-(kx -\omega t)= \omega t - kx$ so that they are traveling in opposite directions. Notice the $-i$ in the backward travelling expression

Using $k$ and $\kappa$ and using $p$ and $\rho$ in the same context is practically begging for errors to be made. Are you sure there isn't a $w$ somewhere that can be brought in to increase the odds even farther?

It's frustrating to say the least but alas this is very standard practice in the literature on acoustics.
